# MySQL Inner Join query giving errors

Tags: php, mysql, database, inner-join

I have two Tables - `char_items` and `items`. item_id is a common field among the two tables.

I want read the item_id from 'char_items' table and use that to obtain other information from the 'items' table based on that item_id. But my query is showing up as incorrect in MySQL. Please help --

```
SELECT * FROM `char_items` WHERE char_id=$char_id && isSlotted=1 INNER JOIN `items` ON char_items.item_id=items.item_id
```

I keep getting the message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `items` ON char_items.item_id=items.item_id
```

LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joins need to happen before the where clause

```
SELECT * 
  FROM char_items c
 INNER 
  JOIN items i
    ON c.item_id = i.item_id
 WHERE char_id = $char_id 
   AND isSlotted = 1
```

Comment: I tried something like this - SELECT * FROM `char_items` INNER JOIN `items` WHERE char_id=$char_id && isSlotted=1  ON char_items.item_id=items.item_id -- But it is still giving similar error. I am very new to MySQL so I am not getting it at all.

Comment: The where clause isn't in the right place still. On should come first.

Comment: Also, I could be wrong, but I think && should be AND.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it working and understand a little more about INNER JOIN :)

Answer (score 0):

where should be after join clause as like below.

```
SELECT * FROM `char_items` INNER JOIN `items` ON char_items.item_id=items.item_id WHERE char_id=$char_id && isSlotted=1;
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer just a couple of minutes before you posted :)